# Ranking Topics by created_at, likes and number of comments

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to create a way to rank topics that are posted by users. I am using this right now:

```
Topic.select("topics.*, (((topics.likes_count - 1) / POW(((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now()-topics.created_at)) / 3600)::integer + 2), 1.5))) AS popularity").order("popularity DESC")
```

And am wondering how to add the number of comments per Topic to it.

topics.rb

```
has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
has_many :commenters, through: :comments
```

comments.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true, touch: true
belongs_to :commenter, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
```

user.rb

```
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :topics #destroyed via the UserDeletionService
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a column called `comments_counter` to the Topic model, and then change comments.rb to include `counter_cache: true` for the `belongs_to :topic` association

More info here, scroll down to counter_cache: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

counter_cache will be far less expensive on the DB and less of a headache than trying to calculate the number of comments per topic on the fly